# MVC4 : Get View or partial (file) name being rendered from extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there any way to get the file name (or view name) being rendered from an extension method. Something like :

```
public static string Something<T>(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<T> helper, int value)
{
     string viewName = ...; // ???
     ...
     return someValueFromViewName;
}
```

** **Edit** **

The suggested question's answer :

```
var webPage = htmlhelper.ViewDataContainer as WebPageBase;
var virtualPath = webPage.VirtualPath;
```

does **not** work, and is *not* an answer to this question. I need the script *being* rendered at call time. If it is a partial, I need that partial name. Those two lines only returns the view being rendered from the controller, and not necessarily the view script being rendered at call time.

** **Edit 2** **

These *also* ddo **not** work. They all return the same value; the controller's view script and not the view script (partial) calling the extension method.

```
var view = htmlhelper.ViewContext.View as BuildManagerCompiledView;
var virtualPath = webPage.ViewPath;
```

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus, so it also applies to MVC4? I have search SO and I didn't find this question.

Comment: Well, it's worth a try a least, from what I looked, properties used are still available...

Comment: the problem with this is that if I'm rendering a partial, I need the partial name, whereas the question you suggest only provides the controller's view script. I need the script being rendered at run-time (the calling script name)

Comment: Try with: `var view = htmlhelper.ViewContext.View as BuildManagerCompiledView;
var virtualPath = webPage.ViewPath;`

Comment: @nemesv, same thing. It returns the controller's view, and not the calling partial script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `WebPageContext.Current.Page.VirtualPath`?

```
public static string Something<T>(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<T> helper, int value)
{
     string viewName = Path.GetFileName(WebPageContext.Current.Page.VirtualPath);

     string someValueFromViewName = viewName.DoSomething();
     return someValueFromViewName;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, this is the same thing as my edit. It returns the controller's view script, and not the partial that is calling my extension method.

Comment: By me (MVC4) it does show the Partial name, how exactly are you calling it? how do you call the partial?

Comment: Stupid IIS cache. You are right it works. Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, all of the other options suggested here are also working for me, though i like my short way (without `as`).

Answer (score 0):

Since views are compiled I think that you would have to inspect the current call stack to be able to determine which partial view that is being rendered.

Getting the name of the partial view code that is calling your code is pretty much like getting the name of the method that is calling you.